# Is there an iOS screen recorder framework for recording demos?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, screen, record

I want to record a demo of my app on the device. For the purpose of recording an in-app demo, is there a framework which can be dropped into an app to record the screen?

Of course this framework would be removed prior to submission to the App Store.

Comment: why not run the app in simulator and record the screen of your mac? Quick time player has a screen recorder, or any software out there.

Comment: Don't know any, but there's a Screen Recorder app in Cydia.

Comment: Quicktime Player on a Mac can record the screen of an attached iOS device. Some other Mac screen-recording apps can also do this. If you want to create the recording directly in your app on the device, you can use the [ReplayKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit), which was added in iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your device is jailbroken, try [this](http://www.ijailbreak.com/applications/cydia-app-display-recorder/):

I dont know about the quality. If you can also demonstrate your app on iOS Simulator, use any Mac screen video capturing programm and record your screen.
After it, cut your iOS frame out and you are done.