# Video Screen Recording In Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the iOS app Display Recorder record the screen without using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090184/how-does-the-ios-app-display-recorder-record-the-screen-without-using-private-ap)

i had done screen recording for my iphone application,its working perfect.it is recording screen within the application,but i need to record any other screens in the iphone with this app,When i Touch the start recording app button ,it need to exit from the app and app must run in background to record the screen.

```
-(IBAction)onStartRecording:(id)sender {
    [((ScreenCaptureView*)self.view) startRecording];
}
-(IBAction)onStopRecording:(id)sender {
    [((ScreenCaptureView*)self.view) stopRecording];
}
```

i Created a class ScreenCaptureView and implement the coding to record the screen there..how it be possible to run this app and record the screen?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi stackiphone, I need to record the screen in my app. In your question you said you were able to record the screen. Can you please provide the sample source code or any reference to achieve that. Many suggested to use this link:                             http://expired-host.no-ip.com/?h=codethink.no-ip.org                But this is not available. I have been trying for the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how to realize screen recording for your iphone application? Or give me some reference,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There was an app called Display recorder who was doing this. Check it [here.](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57455241-285/you-can-now-record-your-ios-devices-screen-with-display-recorder/). But as per [this news](http://www.appolicious.com/articles/12383-display-recorder-makes-brief-appearance-in-itunes-app-store-or-did-it), it is not there any more. So it is not possible for a normal app.

A similar question was asked here [Is there an iOS screen recorder framework for recording demos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108987/is-there-an-ios-screen-recorder-framework-for-recording-demos).

Comment: Now it is called Dpl Recoder: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/dpl-recorder/id585152395?mt=8. Seems it gets more expensive each time.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, So he managed to upload again!

Comment: yeah. the screenshots this time show no screen capture. maybe apple's tester are sometime to lazy to review all parts of an app.